# Multiple filter condition using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the sample excel:

[image]

I want to filter out values when the following conditions met:

- If UCase(Function) <> "BTM" And Result <> ""

My Code is:

```
        Dim range_to_filter4 As Range
        Set range_to_filter4 = .Range("A:G")
        range_to_filter4.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>BTM", Operator:=xlAnd, Field:=3, Criteria2:=""
```

My problem is that, I can't get the expected output. No record found. In my example, I need to get the entire row for PKUMAR168. Is there anything wrong with my code? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not start by recording a macro of applying the filters?

Comment: check if you are on the right sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `with` statement

```
With Range("a:g")
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>BTM"
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria2:=""
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, maybe this will help.

```
Set src_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your_Sheet_Name")

src_sheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>BTM"
src_sheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter Field:=3 Criteria1:=""
```

Comment: or you can use with statement as per what @smallwat3r did. it's the same thing.